# Validating arguments with flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm a completely noob in Flask and as I'm starting to learn it I'm facing some troubles. Specifically, I'd like to validate both the existence and type of some parameters.

Doing some research I found the RequestParser class from flask-restful.

So, this was my approach:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def testing():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
            parser.add_argument('x1', type=float, help="x1 must be float")
            parser.add_argument('x2', type=float, help="x2 must be float")
            parser.add_argument('x3', choices=(1,2), help="x3 must be binary")

            return jsonify({'test': 'ok})
        except:
            pass
```

This works great with my testing code if the inputs are ok:

```
data = {
   "x1" : 100,
   "x2" : 200,
   "x3" : 300
}

BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000"
response = requests.post("{}/predict".format(BASE_URL), json = data)
response.json()

# {'x1': 100.0, 'x2': 200.0, 'x3': 300}
```

However, using:

```
data = {
    "x1" : "a",
    "x2" : 200,
    "x3" : 300
}
```

I started to face `JSONDecodeError`. Using `print(resnpose)` I see that the API returned code 400, but none of the errors. How could I return the erros in form of a dictionary? For example:

```
{"x1" : "x1 should be float"}
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1725, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for misreading the question the first time.

So as per the http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html#error-handling , you can pretty much handle it this way

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument(‘foo’, choices=(‘one’, ‘two’), help=’Bad choice: {error_msg}’)
```

Then,

```
{
"message": { "foo": "Bad choice: three is not a valid choice", }
}
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the traceback of the error?

Comment: Just did it. Thank you.